# sparklyr group by mutate with n_distinct

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I'm using a table where I have to do this operation where I group_by, and mutate by n_distinct, and this is necessary for me to carry out my next step, I'm just showing casing mtcars here because I want to learn how to do this on my dataset

```
tbl_mtcars <- copy_to(sc, mtcars, "spark_mtcars")
tbl_mtcars%>%
group_by(gear)%>%
mutate(n=n_distinct(cyl))
```

Window function `DISTINCT()` is not supported by this database

Comment: if you can't sample your dataset here, please, provide some toy data. `mutate(mtcars, .by = gear, n = n_distinct(cyl))` output have the same 32 lines from mtcars. Aren't you trying to `summarise` instead? `dput(summarise(mtcars, .by = gear, n = n_distinct(cyl)))` wil give you `structure(list(gear = c(4, 3, 5), n = c(2L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`.